# In swift, how can a superclass's function uses subclass's function through protocol/delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, delegates

So I'm writing an iOS app with Swift, and I encounter the following problem:
I have two class A and B, while B is the subclass of A.
Let A has a function a(), and B has a function b(). Now, A will not implement b() and B will not override a(), but a() will be calling b(). In order to do this, I'm trying to use protocol ADelegate, which is a delegate that contains b(). B inherits A and abide by ADelegate. Hence, B must implement b().
Now, say I create an instance of B, let's call it bb. I call bb.a(), which will be calling b(). A's a() is called since a() is only implemented in superclass A. 
Because of this use case, in my implementation of class A, I must call b() (I think there's no way around according to my use case), while b() is only implemented by A's subclass B.
My question is, how can I call b() correctly in A? I think this can be done in Objective C, but I'm not sure how to do in Swift.
What I'm doing now is something like this:

```
var delegate: ADelegate?  // this code is in A
...
self.delegate?.b()
```

However, I don't know how to assign value to delegate. Note that the only instance created is bb() which is an instance of B.

```
protocol ADelegate {
    func b()
}

class A: NSObject {
    var delegate: ADelegate?

    func a() {
        self.delegate?.b()
    }
}

class B: A, ADelegate {

    func b() {

    }
}
```

use case:

```
x = B()
x.a()
```

This is what I have right now, I just want to know how should I assign to self.delegate in A?

Comment: You are mixing delegation and subclassing, split them up until you know exactly what each of them does. And provide the exact situation you explained in the text as code so we can put it into playground and play around with it.

Comment: hi, I will update some illustration code soon, thanks

Comment: also, you are right that I'm mixing delegation and subclassing. So it's like B: A, ADelegate. I know I can separate them and use different method of implementation. I just want to know if I want to do it with B: A, ADelegate, can I achieve what I'm describing?

Comment: just add an illustration, please take a look!

Comment: @luk2302 will be great if you can take a look at my sample code. I understand the implementation is kind of weird, but I just want to know if it's possible for it to work like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works - not making much sense to be itself delegate but okay, it works:

```
let x = B()
x.delegate = x
x.a()
```

Or a little bit more separated:

```
let x = B()
let a : A = x
a.delegate = x
a.a()
```

Comment: Yes it works. super easy can't believe I didn't figure it out. Thank you!